# Why is the KNN using pytorch broadcasting is so slow?

Tags: scikit-learn, pytorch, knn, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to find knn for grid points. This is the code for generating the grid

```
def grid_by(lims=[[0, 1], [0, 1]], size=[28, 28]):
    """
    Creates a tensor of 2D grid points.
    Grid points have one-to-one correspondence with input pixel values that are flattened in row-major order.

    Args:
        lims: [[domain of H], [domain of W]]
        size: [H, W]
    Returns:
        grid: Tensor of shape [(H*W), 2]
    """
    assert len(size) == 2 and len(lims) == len(size)
    expansions = [torch.linspace(start, end, steps) if i != 0 else torch.linspace(end, start, steps) for i, ((start, end), steps) in enumerate(zip(lims, size))]
    grid = torch.index_select(torch.cartesian_prod(*expansions),
                        dim=1,
                        index=torch.tensor([1,0]))
    return grid
```

I made a custom KNN function so that it can run on gpu in pytorch.
The pytorch code looks like the following, assuming L2 distance.

```
def knn(grid, k):
    """
    Brute Force KNN.

    Args:
            grid: Tensor of shape [(H*W), D]
            k: Int representing number of neighbors 
    """
    d = grid.shape[-1]
    Xr = grid.unsqueeze(1)
    Yr = grid.view(1, -1, d)
    distances = torch.sqrt(torch.sum((Xr - Yr)**2, -1))
    dist, index = distances.topk(k, largest=False, dim=-1)
    return dist, index

grid = grid_by().to('cuda')
knn_dist, knn_index = knn(grid, k=10)
```

The sklearn code looks like the following

```
grid = grid_by()
nn = NearestNeighbors(n_jobs=-1)
nn.fit(grid)
knn_dist, knn_index = nn.kneighbors(self.grid, n_neighbors=10)
```

I used broadcasting, so I expected it to run pretty fast on gpu. However, it is way slower than using sklearn NearestNeighbor running on cpu when I measured the running time with `timeit`. What is the reason for this slow speed?

Comment: can you provide full examples of both the pytorch code and sklearn code?

Comment: Yep. I edited the code

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce. I ran the following `timeit` tests on a machine with 64 cores and a 3090 GPU.

`knn` on `cpu`: `786 µs ± 74 µs per loop`

`knn` on `cuda:0`: `197 µs ± 437 ns per loop`

`sklearn` on `cpu` with `n_jobs=-1`: `21.6 ms ± 212 µs per loop`

`sklearn` on `cpu` with `n_jobs=None`: `1.16 ms ± 299 ns per loop`

Comment: I had removed the batch dimension from the original manual knn code for simplicity. I guess broadcasting over the batch dimension was the reason for the slow down then. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Also, when I increase the ```size``` parameter of ```grid_by``` function to ```(224,224)``` and run the code, I get an error like the following. CUDA error: an illegal memory access was encountered
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1. Does this also happen in your case?